# Unable to type in text-box in modal and re-render with new state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, textbox, modal-dialog

I have the following model in my render method:
{

```
showEditModal && <Modal toggleModal={this.togglePageModal} pageModal={true}>
            <h2 style={{ textAlign: "center", width: "100%" }}>
              {rawProjects[selectedProject].name}
            </h2>
            <span
              style={{
                textAlign: "center",
              }}
            >
              {currentStep === 1 && `BASIC DETAILS`}
              {currentStep === 2 && `ARCHITECTURE`}
              {currentStep === 3 && `TEAM`}
            </span>
            <DotSteps
              totalSteps={4}
              currentStep={currentStep}
              onChange={currentStep => this.setState({ currentStep })}
              className="flex-jfe"
            />
            {currentStep === 1 && (
              <div className="w-100 flex flex-col">
                <ContentCard>
                  <span style={{ color: "#5252ED", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                    Type
                  </span>
            <Input>  //the input text box
            label="Project Type"
            type="text"
            placeholder="project type"
            inputId="basicInput"
            value={rawProjects[selectedProject].type} //received from API call where rawProjects is an array 
            onChange={e => this.setState(state => {
              console.log(state.rawProjects[selectedProject], "old check");
              state.rawProjects[selectedProject].type = "new type";
              console.log(state.rawProjects[selectedProject], "new check");
            })}
            
          ></Input>
                </ContentCard>
```

I have an onChange method and I can see that as soon as I click on the text box, the console logs show that the type has been changed to the string "new type". However, I'm unable to actually type in the text box as well as the textbox doesn't update to "new type" string.

Any ideas as to why I'm not able to type in the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

You passed a function in setState. The function should return value.
But you didn't return the value.
Also, you don't have to change the state value directly.

Example:

```
<Input 
    label="Project Type"
    type="text"
    placeholder="project type"
    inputId="basicInput"
    value={rawProjects[selectedProject].type}
    onChange={e => this.setState(state => {
        return {project_type: "new type"};
    })}
></input>
```

Comment: I don't need to set it explicitly to "new type" I need to set it to whatever value the user inputs. Currently, the textbox doesn't seem to be working as the user can't type in it.

Comment: Also, where is project_type coming from please? I tried to use rawProjects[selectedProject].type in your solution instead of project_type and its giving me errors that it needs a parent

Answer (score 0):

In controlled component, user input is kept in its own state and input element value should be by its own state.
But now your input value isn't updated by state.
I mean that you should make state with 'project_type' key for input element value.
Then, you should update the input value by its state.

Example:

```
constructor(props){
    this.state = {projectType: ''};
}

//Whenever you receive api call, this.setState({projectType: receivedValue});

handleChange = (e) => {
   this.setState({projectType: e.target.value});
}

render() {
   return(
      <input
          value={this.state.projectType}
          onChange={this.handleChange}>
      </input>
   );
}
```